# Power Automate flow in an existing Sharepoint Online list - will it copy and be usable when a new Sharepoint list is created from existing list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

Our organization is migrating from SharePoint 2010 with Nintex Workflows to SharePoint Online with Power Automate. Our existing SP2010 lists are running Nintex Workflows to send out notification emails to specific parties (determined by user inputs in the SharePoint list).

Due to the limits of SP lists when lists have more than 5000 items, we regularly save the list as a template and create an new list to work from. The existing Nintex flows are copied into the new list, and work (largely) without an issue in the new list. (If changes are needed, I do need to export the workflow in the list it was created in, and import into the current list prior to making modifications.)

In SP Online, it appears that if we create a list from an existing list, the Power Automate flow we've created continues to point it's trigger function to the original list. Is there a way to copy an existing list in SP Online, and have the associated notification workflow point to the new list, while leaving the workflow in previous lists point to their respective lists as well (sometimes our items in previous lists are modified and need new notifications sent to the affected parties)?

Thank you,
Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to copy an existing list in SP Online and have the associated notification flow point to the new list.

As a workaround, after copying the existing list, select the flow and save as a copy, then update the associated list to make it run in the new list.

[image]